# Array.prototype.fill({}) references

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reference

Can somebody explain please how this code works under the hood:

```
let arr = Array(3).fill({}) // [{}, {}, {}]
arr[0].hi = "hi"            // [{ hi: "hi" }, { hi: "hi" }, { hi: "hi" }]
```

Why does this reference all elements? And how would I reference only the first one?

Comment: Each array element is pointing to the same object.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @ElAoutarHamza

Comment: You can reference the first element without referencing the rest of the elements by copying it's value, setting the value to something else and reinserting it like this: `let f = arr[0]; f={hi: "hi"}; arr[0] = first;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filling each position in the array with the same reference of an object, it is the same as

```js
let a = {};
const b = a;
a.hi = 'hi';
console.log(b);
```